# Sitecore Control to select inherited field?

Tags: templates, data-exchange-framework, tree-list, inheritance

Using Sitecore 9.0.1, I need to select a field but this field may be inherited from a base template. ie. I wont the content author to be able to select a field name using a suitable control and this field may come from an inherited templated.

Using the treeview, I can only select fields on the parent template and not inherited fields. How can I allow the user to select an inherited field using the treeview or another control?

Comment: Could you clarify what you aim to achieve by "selecting a field", please?   Further - I believe these two posts may be what you're looking for. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/591/restrict-item-by-base-template-on-a-field-includetemplatesforselection?rq=1 and https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2312/display-field-value-in-drop-link-field

Comment: Hi Mark. Im using the Data Exchange Framework and in a particular place, there is a tree control that you use to select a field of your template to bind data to - But when I go to my template, it doesn't list inherited fields of the template ..